# Copy web-link with title in Android 7

Tags: stock-android

How do I copy and share a link with title text?

For example, when I 'share' a link from chrome it just sends the URI.
I want to also add the title of the page and then the URI link.

Comment: I'm having a hard time trying to understand what you are trying to do,  won't it be easier if you copied separately the link and added the title?

Comment: To where you want to share it?

Comment: Hi @xavier_fakerat, that will take many extra steps and switching back-and-forth between applications.

Comment: Hi @SagarV, I just want to copy to email or chat-app. I remember when I had the HTC, all links I copied had a text title preceding the link. Can something similar be done via a 3rd party app?

Comment: The WSJ app I use still has this feature: when I click to "share" an article it will be the text-title, space char, and then the URI.